# Find parent property of a child via console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console.log

If i know some property **foo.foo** exists, is there anyway of finding the parent property without source code to directly call it via console?

[picture reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHVWr.png)

Comment: I think you have to provide a more concrete example. I can only speculate about what you mean with "parent property", but the answer is likely "no".

Comment: I think you can do that until you're in the scope where foo is. Add a breakpoint (in dev tools -> sources -> filename) where your foo is and then you can have access to properties of foo. If I got your question right.

Comment: i dont mean the properties of foo, i mean the parent object calling the property.
**parent**.foo.foo

Comment: I think you are asking "I know an object exists with the property `foo`. Can I somehow get a reference to that object by just supplying the property name?". The answer to this is generally "no". But if that object is in global scope you can iterate over all global variables, check whether any of them is an object and has the property `foo`. But if you have full control over the code you should design it differently.